# geom_path grouped and path ordered by categorical factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, factominer

I am looking for a solution to order the pathway of geom_path based on a defined order set to a factor.

I have been working with the fist two PCA dimensions. Using `library("factoextra")` and `library("FactoMineR")` I generate my figure with `fviz_pca_ind()`.

```
raa_male <- fviz_pca_ind(
  pca.data,
  fill.ind = male_raa.df$Season,
  pointsize = male_raa.df$BRI,
  pointshape = 21,
  repel = TRUE
)
```

The data is arranged in to individuals (shown by text labels).

[image]

Using `geom_path` I want to connect points of the same individual, by order the path way the factor season, `c(Autumn, Winter, Spring)`. However I am having difficulty doing this

```
male_raa.df$Season <- factor(male_raa.df$Season, levels = c("Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"))

raa_male +
  geom_path(
    arrow = arrow(angle = 15, ends = "last", type = "closed"),
    alpha = 0.2,
    aes(group = male_raa.df$TagID)
  )
```

[image]

The ordering set to factor does not appear translating to ordering of the geom_path pathway.

Comment: I believe `geom_path` uses the order of appearance rather than order of the factor, so you may need to add a sorting step first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a smaller example, compare the original and sorted version. `geom_path` is ordered based on the order of appearance in the data, so if you want it to reflect an ordered factor, sort by that first.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3,
                  y = c(1,2,1),
                  season = LETTERS[1:3])
df1$season = factor(df1$season, levels = c("B","C","A"))

library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
ggplot(df1, aes(x,y, label = season)) +
    geom_path(arrow = arrow(angle = 15, ends = "last", type = "closed")) +
    geom_label()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df1 %>% arrange(season), aes(x,y, label = season)) +
    geom_path(arrow = arrow(angle = 15, ends = "last", type = "closed"),) +
    geom_label()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jon this solution works great